# Criar Trigger para alterar registro somente na modificação de um campo

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Tenho uma tabela de cadastro do SQL Server, tenho uma coluna que apresenta o status desse cadastro `('A','I','S','C')`.

Criei um campo com nome `Update_data`, que receberá um datatime toda vez que o cliente alterar o status do cadastro. Isso também vale para um insert.

Estou com dúvidas, pois nunca criei uma Trigger em sql server.

Ex: da minha tabela

```
ID | Processo | status | Update_data
1  | A33      | A      | null
2  | A34      | I      | null
3  | A55      | A      | null
```

Não consegui avançar no seguinte exemplo abaixo trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER atualizaData
ON cadastro
 AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS
IF INSERT OR UPDATE(status)
BEGIN
UPDATE cadastro
      SET Update_data = GETDATE()
WHERE id = id_que_foi_modifica/inserida
END
```

Ao final, será atualizado com a data atual somente se houver modificação ou inserção no campo da situação.

Comment: Qual coluna que identifica cada linha de forma única?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O 1º passo é colocar uma `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT` na sua coluna `Update_data` para não ter que se preocupar com o `INSERT` (a data é atualizada no momento que o registo é adicionado):

```
ALTER TABLE cadastro ADD CONSTRAINT cadastro_updatedata DEFAULT(GETDATE()) FOR Update_data
```

Depois basta criar o `TRIGGER` apenas para o `UPDATE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER atualizaData ON cadastro
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(status)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE      CD
        SET         Update_data = GETDATE()
        FROM        deleted     D
        INNER JOIN  cadastro    CD ON CD.id = D.id
    END
```

A tabela `deleted` contém os registos que acabaram de ser atualizados (existe também a tabela `inserted`, que contém os valores mais atuais).

Se quiser mais informação sobre estas tabelas nos `TRIGGER` do **SQL**, aceda aqui: [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Eis uma possibilidade:

```
-- código #1

CREATE TRIGGER atualizadata
     on CADASTRO
     after INSERT, UPDATE as
begin

-- verifica se há algo a processar
IF not exists (SELECT * from INSERTED)
  return;

-- verifica se a coluna status consta na lista de inserção/atualização
IF not UPDATE (status)
  return;

-- detecção do evento
declare @isINSERT bit, @isUPDATE bit;
set @isUPDATE= exists (SELECT * from DELETED);
set @isINSERT= not @isUPDATE;

--
UPDATE C
  set update_data= cast (current_timestamp as date)
  from cadastro as C
       inner join INSERTED as I on I.chave = C.chave
       left join DELETED as D on D.chave = C.chave
  where @isINSERT = 'true'
        or (@isUPDATE = 'true' and (D.status <> I.status));
end;
go
```

Não testei; pode conter erro(s).

Sugiro a leitura do artigo “[Armadilhas na programação de procedimentos de gatilho (*trigger*)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/artigos/)”, onde estão relacionadas algumas das arapucas na programação de *triggers*.